# How to create custom increment column item id in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

How to create custom Auto increment column item id in SharePoint? 
What I want,
When a user creates a new item in a list then this combination code auto-generate. 
Anyone please give some link or guide me how to achieve this.

**for example combination.**
Purchase order =**PO**
Department =Dept like  IT, HR, Admin.
2018-2019= **1819**
serial No start = **000001**
We want a combination of PO+Dept+ 1819-0000001
Like below example.
When HR team create form then generate below format.
**POHR1819000001**
When IT team create the form then below format generate.
 POIT1819000001

Answer (score 1):

You can create the required combination ID using SharePoint designer workflow and set that value to a custom column.

Comment: Thank Aditya for your suggestion, can you plz Share a link if any.

Answer (score 0):

Download [SharePoint designer 2013](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ie/download/details.aspx?id=35491).

Connect to your site by SharePoint designer, then you could create workflow for your list and update list item field value(screenshots of SharePoint 2013 workflow).

[image]
[image]

You could refer below official guideline.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/creating-a-workflow-by-using-sharepoint-designer-and-the-sharepoint-wo